# Pela Ferramenta do Desenvolvedor é possível ativar o Teclado do Dispositivo? No DevTools do Chrome da para simular o teclado?

Tags: html, google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, ui, dev-tools

Estou testando um site na versão mobile pelo DevTools do Google Chrome. Eu sei que pela Ferramenta do Desenvolvedor além de poder testar o site de forma responsiva tb tem as opções de testar para cada tipo de *device* tipo iPhone5 / 6/7/8, iPad, Galaxy, Nexus, etc... E tb reparei que é possível simular o "frame" de cada um desses aparelhos. Dessa forma da para ter uma noção mais real de como vai ficar o layout do site na tela do smartphone.

**Veja que é possível simular a resolução e o modelo do dispositivo.** (Mas tb queria poder mostrar o teclado...)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida é a seguinte. Teria como além de simular a "carcaça" do dispositivo e a sua resolução, também simular o Teclado Mobile?

**Existe no DevTools a opção de mostra um teclado mobile para visualizar como o site ficaria com ele aberto?**

Tipo como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível simular um protótipo da exibição utilizando o Chrome com o device Nexus 5x, conforme print:

[image: Chrome devtools Nexus 5x keyboard simulator]

Por ser um protótipo, você não terá a funcionalidade do teclado. Não encontrei a mesma funcionalidade para outros dispositivos.

Comment: É isso mesmo. Parece que só o Nexus5X tem esse teclado, e realmente ele é apenas uma "simulação" não é um teclado interativo de verdade. Mas já serve pra ter uma previa visual de como vão ficar as coisas. Vlw